# Extract variable number of columns for a matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, python-2.7

I want to extract out some specified columns from the matrix. My matrix being

```
matrix=[[1,2,3,4,5],
        [6,7,8,9,10],
        [6,4,3,1,2],
        [2,3,4,5,6]]
expected result: [[3,4],[8,9],[3,1],[4,5]] for 2 columns
expected result in case of 3 column:[[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[6,4,3],[2,3,4]]
```

I am trying to use the method given below:

```
def func(matrix, p):
     return np.vstack([a[i] for a in matrix])
```

The above method just returns to be a single column, however I want to write a method which takes in multiple columns as input (e.g. the expected results for 2 & 3 columns), also my input number of columns vary each time. Please suggest a suitable method to extract these columns in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure Python, you can extract columns `1`, `5` and `7` by using the following nested list comprehension:

```
[[a[i] for i in (1, 5, 7)] for a in matrix]
```

Example usage for your input:

```
>>> [[a[i] for i in (0, 1, 2)] for a in matrix]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8], [6, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

In cases like this where you want to extract a real slice of columns, you can also use list slicing:

```
>>> [a[0:3] for a in matrix]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8], [6, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: @user869790: Before you posted that comment, I already added an example for your specific use case. Indexing starts with `0` in Python (and most any other programming language I know). Don't know why you get a 4x4 matrix back instead of 4x3, this seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I am getting a (4 x 3) matrix (as in question). I posted my comment before the edit...therefore did not see it...thanks a ton for the help :)

Comment: @user: Added another way which is faster for those kinds of special cases where you need a consecutive set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to work within Numpy you could use slicing:

```
def col_slice(arr, col_start=None, total_cols=None):
    """ take a slice of columns from col_start for total_cols """
    return arr[:,col_start:col_start + total_cols]
```

Examples:

```
In [22]: col_slice(your_matrix, col_start=2, total_cols=2)
Out[22]:
array([[3, 4],
       [8, 9],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 5]])

In [23]: col_slice(your_matrix, col_start=0, total_cols=3)
Out[23]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 4, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```